# return value of r/foldcat changes based on size of data

Tags: clojure

On running the following code -

```
(r/foldcat (r/mapcat prepare-event events))
```

1) When `(count events) ->100`, the above code returns a data of type of `java.util.ArrayList`
2) When `(count events) ->1000`, the above code returns a data of type of `clojure.core.reducers.Cat`

and the above behavior is breaking my code, why would it return different types depending on if the data was parallelized or not using the `r/cat` combine fn ? Shouldn’t it always return realized data ?

Comment: This is an implementation detail, you shouldn’t be relying on these types. As always, creating a minimal reproducible example helps https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Clojuredocs has an example of the behavior: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.reducers/foldcat

`clojure.core.reducers.Cat` is Seqable and can be used for further reduction.
Why is it breaking your code?